# Git - push just the last commit

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I have the following commits A->B->C->D. If i push D's SHA, i know that it will take also A,B,C along.

My requirement is a bash script that rebases the last commit and makes it first so it won't have any dependency.

So, A->B->C->D should become D->A->B->C so that i can use D's SHA in the push.

I've tried doing it multiple times, but i can't manage to get it done without breaking anything.

Have you done this before, or do you have any thoughts on how to do this in a bash script in order to be easily re-used?

Comment: What if you create a new branch NewBranch from the parent of A, and then cherrypick D onto it, followed by cherry picking A,B, and C? Of coarse you can push after the initial cherrypick.

Comment: How did you end up in a situation where you want to do this repeatedly?  If commits A, B, C and D are truly independent and can be moved around like that, you should put them all on separate branches and merge them in when you're done.  If they aren't independent, then there's no guarantee such an operation wouldn't have merge conflicts that need to be resolved by hand.

Comment: I'm using submodules, and i have a script for automatically tagging the submodule from a branch and push it to a specific remote. The problem is that after pushing the submodule, i need to commit it from the parent and push it to origin. I thought on rebasing since the user might have commits pending to be pushed, and don't want to push everything , only the submodule's "pointer". So in my case, D should be independent from A,B,C

Comment: you could define a custome `EDITOR` for interactive rebase to use which reorders the commits to achieve this.

Comment: True, but this is something that users should do as easy as possible, so after executing a bash script for tagging the submodule and pushing it to origin, I need also an automatic way of pushing the commit from the parent repo

Comment: Aha, you had not mentioned submodules earlier (or "sobmodules" as some call them :-) ).  They complicate things because submodule IDs don't show up properly in some diffs (I have not experimented with them recently, maybe since 1.6 they work better now).

Answer (score 0):

There is no fully general solution to this, because comparing `D` with `C` will depend on what's in `C`, which in turn depends on what's in `B`, and so on.  As a silly but simple example, suppose `C`-vs-`D` includes this change:

```
 The quick brown
-sheep
+foxes
 jump over the
 lazy dog.
```

But, in the version before version `A`, this reads:

```
 The quick brown
 sheep
 jumps over the
 lazy dog.
```

The correct adjustment is no doubt to make `D` use the singular, i.e., the change you want is now to replace `sheep` with `fox` (singular).

How will you automate the idea that the plural of `sheep` is `sheep` but the plural of `fox` is `foxes`, and the verb number (`jumps` vs `jump`) must match the noun?

That aside, in general, a rebase is simply a series of cherry-pick operations.  To reproduce the `A`, then `B`, then `C`, then `D` sequence on some new base, you cherry-pick commit `A` (making a new commit, `A'`), then cherry-pick `B` onto `A'` making a `B'`, then cherry-pick `C` onto `B'`, and so on.  To change the order, you simply change the order of cherry-picking operations.

Each commit can be labeled with a branch or tag name, so if you have this:

```
... - A - B - C - D   <-- yourbranch
```

we would want to do this—let's start by labeling the end of the `...` sequence as commit `o` and call it `start`:

```
$ git branch start yourbranch~4

... - o                   <-- start
        \
          A - B - C - D   <-- yourbranch
```

Now we'll cherry-pick `D` onto a new branch `tmp`, which we create starting from commit `o`:

```
$ git checkout -b tmp start

... - o                   <-- start, tmp
        \
          A - B - C - D   <-- yourbranch
```

A successful cherry-pick creates new commit `D'`:

```
$ git cherry-pick yourbranch

         D'               <-- tmp
        /
... - o                   <-- start
        \
          A - B - C - D   <-- yourbranch
```

Let's now cherry-pick `A` through `C` but add yet another branch label, `tmp2`:

```
$ git checkout -b tmp2
$ git cherry-pick yourbranch~4..yourbranch~1   # pick A-C all at once

             A'- B'- C'   <-- tmp2
           /
         D'               <-- tmp
        /
... - o                   <-- start
        \
          A - B - C - D   <-- yourbranch
```

Now we can delete the branch-name `yourbranch` entirely, making it look as though commits `A` through `D` are gone (they aren't, really, since git keeps things around for 30 days by default), and once we've done that we can rename `tmp` and/or `tmp2`.

Each cherry-pick can require manual intervention (manually fixing singular-vs-plural or whatever), so while you could automate some of this, you must be prepared to do something about failure.  It's also odd (as noted in comments) that you should have to do this repeatedly: it suggests something is weird in your work-flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain this, i'll try giving a try this way, since in my case D doesn't depend on A-B-C

Comment: In your case (moving submodule points) you might be able to use the rebase script's trick of cherry picking onto an anonymous head, and moving the branch name at the very end of the operation.  See the code for the interactive rebase script (it's a shell script, in the `git-core` directory—that location depends on your system—named `git-rebase--interactive`).